# How do you programmatically check a checkbox column in a datagridview? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I am looping through rows in a datagridview and need to check checkboxes in the checkbox column in certain records, but I don't know how??

Comment: `for each dgvr as datagridviewrow in dgv.rows` // `dgvr.Cells(X).Value = True`  you dont need to set the current cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by using the following code:

```
 Dim CurRow As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

    DataGridView1(0, CurRow).Value = True
```

Comment: you can use datagridview1.currentrow.cells("Your checkbox cell name").value = true to shorten your code

Comment: @Muj I am trying to get my rep up, can you up vote my answer?